# T-SQL XML - Any elements exists

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to find out if any xml elements exists under an element. There is a possibility of multiple elements under entity or no element. below are examples of input xml (stripped out versions for readability)

```
declare @xml xml= '<entity name="User" />'
declare @xml xml= '<entity name="User"> <email>s@s.com</email></entity>
declare @xml xml= '<entity name="User"> <admin>1</admin></entity>

select IsExists = ISNULL(@xml.value('(entity/text())[1]','VARCHAR(max)'), 'N')
```

I am trying to use value and trying to extract text out. but it doesn't seems to work. Any help or suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you have in mind.

```
declare @xml1 xml= '<entity name="User" />'
declare @xml2 xml= '<entity name="User"><email>s@s.com</email><email>t@s.com</email></entity>'
declare @xml3 xml= '<entity name="User"><admin>1</admin></entity>'

select @xml1.exist('entity/*') as [xml1?], 
    @xml2.exist('entity/*') as [xml2?], 
    @xml3.exist('entity/*') as [xml3?]

xml1? xml2? xml3?
----- ----- -----
0     1     1
```

If you want the text of all the elements.

```
select CAST(@xml1.query('entity/*') as varchar(20)) as [text1], 
    CAST(@xml2.query('entity/*') as varchar(45)) as [text2], 
    CAST(@xml3.query('entity/*') as varchar(20)) as [text3]

text1                text2                                         text3
-------------------- --------------------------------------------- --------------------
                     <email>s@s.com</email><email>t@s.com</email>  <admin>1</admin>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
-- Sample Data
declare @xmldata table(xmlid INT IDENTITY, fragments XML);

insert @xmldata(fragments)
values('<entity name="User" />'),('<entity name="User"> <email>s@s.com</email></entity>'),
      ('<entity name="User"> <admin>1</admin></entity>');

-- Solution    
SELECT 
  XMLID            = xmlid,
  ChildNodeExists  = IIF(ch.E.query('.') IS NULL,0,1),
  ChildNodeDetails = ch.E.query('.')
FROM        @xmldata AS x
OUTER APPLY x.fragments.nodes('/*[1]/*') AS ch(E);
--OUTER APPLY x.fragments.nodes('/entity[1]/*') AS ch(E); --<< For "entity" specifically
```

**Results:**

```
XMLID       ChildNodeExists ChildNodeDetails
----------- --------------- -----------------------------
1           0               NULL
2           1               <email>s@s.com</email>
3           1               <admin>1</admin>
```